# Spring reactive: Chaining repository results

Tags: spring, project-reactor, reactive

```
Repository repo
Repository otherRepo

foreach entity : repo.FindAll() {
    entityFind = otherRepo.FindById(entity.Prop)
    if (entityFind != null) {
        return entityFind 
    }
}
```

How could I do this using the spring reactive?

I could use blockFirst() to search in otherRepo but it would break the reaction chain

I also have tried use a handle() to control the flow but I don't get to break the flow when I find an item

Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have repos like this, for each record of repo1, if you need to find a record from repo2, you could probably join the tables using spring data JPQL & use your custom method instead as your current approach could have performance impact.

As you seem to be interested only in the first record, Just to give you an idea, We can achieve something like this.

```
return Flux.fromIterable(repo.findAll()) //assuming it returns a list
           .map(entity -> otherRepo.findById(entity.property)) // for each entity we query the other repo
           .filter(Objects::nonNull) // replace it with Optional::isPresent if it is optional
           .next();   //converts the flux to mono with the first record
```

Comment: I use Cassandra. The problem with this solution is that if you have n elements in repo1 and this is found in repo2 in the first ones, unnecessary searches will be executed in repo2. Thanks for you answer

Answer (score 1):

The answer from `vins` is assuming non-reactive repository, so here it is in a fully reactive style:

```
return repo.findAll() //assuming reactive repository, which returns Flux<Entity>
    .flatMap(entity -> otherRepo.findById(entity.property)) //findById returns an empty Mono if id not found, which basically gets ignored by flatMap
    .next(); //first record is turned into a Mono, and the Flux is cancelled
```

Note that as you've stated, this can lead to unnecessary requests being made to Cassandra (and then cancelled by the `next()`). This is due to `flatMap` allowing several concurrent requests (256 by default). You can either reduce the `parallelism` of `flatMap` (by providing a second parameter, an `int`) or use `concatMap` to perform `findById` queries serially.